# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'color_code' cannot be null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables products and colors.

I want to store multiple rows in multiple tables within my database. My controller is currently not storing multiple values, it is only saving one row in my products and item lists tables.

**How to bet? If it was empty.**

blade

```
<div class="row no-gutters mb-1">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="color_name" class="ml-1">color_name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="color_code" class="ml-1">color_code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
        <a onclick="deleteColor()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

ProductController.php

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = Product::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'latin' => $request->latin,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'discount' => $request->discount,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'keywords' => $request->keywords,
        'descriptions' => $request->descriptions,
    ]);
    $product->categories()->attach($request->category_id);

    $colorCodes = $request->color_code;
    $colorNames = $request->color_name;

    foreach ($colorCodes as $key => $color_code) {
        if ($request->color_code != null && $request->color_name != null) {
            $color = new Color;
            $color->product_id = $product->id;
            $color->color_code = $color_code;
            $color->color_name = $colorNames[$key];
            $color->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

To determine if there are any results you can do any of the following:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'color_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `colors` (`product_id`, `color_code`, `color_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (20, #FFFFFF, ?, 2021-07-29 18:38:17, 2021-07-29 18:38:17))

Comment: You are sending `?` as a color_name

Comment: `$colorNames[$key]` is apparently null. You check for `$request->color_name` is not null, but you should probably check if `$colorNames[$key]` is not null instead.

Comment: Can you send complete code?